# Поиск элементов на странице и API VK

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Почему, если данные в массив userData, подгружать через контакт, и потом создать список ul , из этих данных и если попробовать перебрать элементы с классом .igrost

, которые находятся в блоке muz, то ничего не найдёт?

http://plnkr.co/edit/5hH9iEYjQ29oB6XUDYlo?p=preview

Я попробовал облегчить код, сделал его без контакта и теперь он находит элементы, а с контактом не находит, почему?

https://jsfiddle.net/049x0eeL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="http://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1 id="headerInfo"></h1>

    <span class="igrost">play</span>

    <ul class='muz' id='muz'>
    </ul>

     <div class="progress">
         <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" data-role="progressbar" style="width: 0%"></div>
      </div>

</div>

 <script src="script.js"></script>


  </body>

</html>





function foo() {

    VK.init({
            apiId: 5580872
        });


    VK.Auth.login(function(response){

        if(response.session){


            VK.api('audio.get', {}, response => {
                if(response.error){
                    alert(response.error.error_msg);
                }
                else{
                    let userData = response.response;

                    for(var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++){
                    var ul = document.querySelector('.muz');
                    var li = document.createElement('li');

                li.innerHTML = '<span class="igrost">'+'play '+'</span>' + userData[i].artist + ' - ' + userData[i].title
                    ul.appendChild(li)

                    }

                }
            });



        }
        else{
            alert('Не удалось авторизироваться')
        }
    }, 8);
}
foo()

    var igrost = muz.querySelectorAll('.igrost')
    console.log(igrost)
```

///////////////////////////////////////

```
<ul class='muz' id='muz'>
    </ul>

let userData = ['sdfs', 'ggggggg', 'uuuu'];

    for(var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++){
                var ul = document.querySelector('.muz');
                var li = document.createElement('li');

                li.innerHTML = '<span class="igrost">' +' play ' +'</span>' + '<span>' +userData[i] +'</span>'
                ul.appendChild(li)
    }

 var igrost = muz.querySelectorAll('.igrost')
    console.log(igrost)



  for(var m = 0; m < igrost.length; m++){
    igrost[m].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                console.log(e.target)
            })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что методы `VK.Auth.login()` и `VK.api()` - асинхронные. Чтобы вы поняли, что такое асинхронные методы, я постараюсь вам объяснить на примере ВК.

Представьте себе, что ВК начал жутко лагать. Запросы к API осуществляются долго, но вам надо вызвать какой-нибудь метод API:

```
VK.api('users.get', {}, response => {
    alert(response.response[0].first_name + ' ' + response.response[0].last_name);
});

alert('Привет!');
```

Если бы метод `VK.api()` был синхронным (на самом деле он асинхронный, но просто представьте, что он синхронный), то следующие инструкции в сценарии (а именно - `alert('Привет!')`) выполнились бы только после того, как выполнился бы запрос к API. А в нашем примере ВКонтакте-то лагает, поэтому наш сценарий просто бы завис и стал дожидаться успешного запроса к API. Но в конечном счете, после заметной задержки, мы бы получили сначала наши имя с фамилией, а затем `Привет!`.

Именно поэтому тяжелые, ресурсоемкие и долгие методы обычно делают асинхронными, чтобы они не блокировали работу сценария. Когда интерпретатор встречает асинхронный метод, он не дожидается, пока тот выполнится, а сразу переходит к следующим инструкциям. В примере выше `VK.api()` - разумеется, асинхронный метод. Как думаете, в каком порядке будут выполнены алерты? В таком: сначала `Привет!`, а затем ваши имя с фамилией.

Теперь по поводу вашего кода. Я слегка упрощу пример для лучшей читаемости. Вы внутри асинхронного метода создаете элементы DOM:

```
VK.api('audio.get', {}, response => {
   let userData = response.response;

   for (let i = 0; i < userData.length; i++){
       let ul = document.querySelector('.muz');
       let li = document.createElement('li');

       li.innerHTML = '<span class="igrost">' + 'play ' + '</span>' + userData[i].artist + ' - ' + userData[i].title;
       ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}); 

let igrost = document.querySelectorAll('.muz .igrost');
console.log(igrost);
```

А затем, в последних строчках моего примера, вы пытаетесь получить созданные элементы. Но для строчки `let igrost = document.querySelectorAll('.muz .igrost')` этих элементов еще не существует! А все потому, что она была вызвана до того, как элементы `.igrost` были созданы при обращении к API.

Всё, что создается внутри асинхронных методов, следует обрабатывать только там же - в этих же асинхронных методах. То есть пример выше следует переписать так:

```
VK.api('audio.get', {}, response => {
   let userData = response.response;

   for (let i = 0; i < userData.length; i++){
       let ul = document.querySelector('.muz');
       let li = document.createElement('li');

       li.innerHTML = '<span class="igrost">' + 'play ' + '</span>' + userData[i].artist + ' - ' + userData[i].title;
       ul.appendChild(li);
    }

    let igrost = document.querySelectorAll('.muz .igrost');
    console.log(igrost);
});
```

Да, это создаст сильную вложенность кода. Но тут вам поможет только такая вещь, как Promises, которую я предлагаю вам изучить самостоятельно:

- [О Promises на Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Хороший обучающий материал на эту тему на learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)
- [Обещания JavaScript - статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/)