# Можно ли "зашить" chrome.storage.sync. get/set в отдельные функции и возвращать из них результат?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Есть вопрос который давно меня мучает. Функции вроде `chrome.storage.sync` имеют какой-то механизм защиты что-ли или просто в области видимости дело, непонятно.

Пишу приложение, уже задавал вопросы по методу сохранения данных, но все же необходимо сократить код так что-бы функции типа `chrome.storage.sync.get()` или `chrome.storage.sync.set()` были зашиты в отдельные функции в примерно такой конструкции:

```
function get_option_storage(option_name) {
    var result = false;

    chrome.storage.sync.get( option_name, function(func_result) {
        result = func_result;
    });

    return result; 
}
```

и для установки

```
function set_option_storage(option_name, option_value) {
    var result = false;

    chrome.storage.sync.set( {option_name: option_value}, function() {
        result = true;
    });

    return result;
}
```

Пришел к этому из-за высокого количества запросов на сохранение и чтение данных из хранилища, поэтому хочу зашить в отдельные функции методы работы с хранилищем и вызывать уже свои, как это можно сделать и можно ли вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почти все методы `chrome.*`, имеющие коллбеки — асинхорнные. Соответственно, асинхорнные методы не возвращают какие-либо данные. Это не механизм защиты и даже не область видимости — это фича, которую завезли для увеличения скорости сценариев JavaScript.

О том, что такое асинхронные методы, я, как мне кажется, доступно объяснил в ответе на этот вопрос: [Поиск элементов на странице и API VK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/598556/212210). Если интересно, то почитайте.

**Что можно сделать:**

1. Используйте Promises. Статьи по этой теме:

   - [О Promises на Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
   - [Хороший обучающий материал на эту тему на learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)
   - [Обещания JavaScript - статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/)
2. Используйте готовое решение в виде полифилла от Mozilla: [mozilla/webextension-polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill). Он немного сыроват, но добавить поддержку Promises с ним довольно просто. Обратите внимание на то, что данный полифилл покрывает не все методы (некоторые непопулярные методы придется добавлять ручками), а также немного меняет API.

Но от кастомных функций вида get*, которые что-то возвращают через `return`, все же придется отказаться. Единственное, что могу посоветовать — перестраивайте структуру приложения или используйте коллбеки вместо `return`.